Finding solution to a SDE with absolute value terms
Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion. Justify the following stochastic differential equation has only one solution (in which sense?) and find the solution.
$dX_t = X_t dt+(1-e^{-|X_t|})X_tdB_t$
My attempt is to use global Lipschitz and linear growth property to prove existence and pathwise uniqueness of the SDE, then use the substitution $Y_t =e^{-t}X_t$ to get rid of the $dt$ term, but this results in a complicated form in the $dB_t$ part. In particular, I don't see how I can use something like Ito's formula when there is absolute value involved...

$dB_t$-parts more complicated than $a(t)+b(t)X_t$ usually lead to explicitly unsolvable SDEs. Here a list of what you can hope for.

Lipschitz yes, so you have a strong solution. 0 attainable? Probably not, it is like a GBM with vol going to 0 near 0, so drift will dominate. This means you probably can drop the absolute value. But then, you still need to find a clever transformation.
